# Im trying to find a way to make it so when it goes below a certain y the text will change to a red color (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

```
// Background

var backgroundt = createSprite(200,200,200,200);
backgroundt.setAnimation("pine_trees_1");

// Bee
var bee1 = createSprite(200,200,200,200);
bee1.setAnimation("bee_1");
bee1.x = 200;
bee1.y = 200;

// Draw Function

function draw() {
  bee1.x = bee1.x - 2;
  bee1.y = bee1.y + 4;
  
  drawSprites();
  
  
  fill("yellow");
  textFont("Times New Roman");
  textSize(50);
  text("Honey!", 138,196);
}

// Drawing the sprites
drawSprites();

var y2 = 398;

while(bee1.y < y2) {
  fill("red");
  textFont("Times New Roman");
  textSize(50);
  text("Honey!", 138,196);
}
```

Im trying to get the Y Value of the bee but i dont know if its possible, if it isnt is there another way?I was thinking if this couldnt work maybe a why to have the text teleport around the screen? This is p5.js btw.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop for this task. The [`draw()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw) function is continuously executed. Just use a different [`fill()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/fill) color when  the condition is met:

```js
var y2 = 398;

function draw() {
    bee1.x = bee1.x - 2;
    bee1.y = bee1.y + 4;
  
    drawSprites();
  
    if (bee1.y < y2) {
        fill("red");
    } else {
        fill("yellow"); 
    }
    textFont("Times New Roman");
    textSize(50);
    text("Honey!", 138,196);
}
```

Comment: i just got a bunch of errors saying its not made

Comment: Never mind thanks i got it working. Sorry for my bad wording!